# Defining custom HTML5 boolean attributes in Django widgets

Tags: python, django, html

Already in the development version, https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20684, you can define custom HTML5 boolean attributes to widgets by setting the value to True.

For example:

```
name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'customattr': True})
```

Will show up like this:

```
<input name="name" type="text" value="A name" customattr />
```

https://github.com/django/django/commit/e61d99d96daedfea2f6ba071945ef0d2f86883c7

My question is, what could be a nice workaround for this in 1.7.1?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#required

Comment: @madzohan I am talking about defining any attribute, without the need of having a value like ``<input type="text" name="name" attr />`` and not ``<input type="text" name="name" attr="value" />``. required is just an example. I will update my question with a proper explanation